# Add DataMember and DataContract onbuild

Tags: wcf, silverlight

We are developing an Silverlight with Wcf business application. We are using Wcf DataContract and DataMember.

We are setting DataMember at all fields and DataContract(IsReference=true) on all classes. Can we somehow set the compiler to automatically add DataMember and DataContract onbuild so we can skip to add DataMember and DataContract? :).
In other words can we set a rule that adds DataContract on all classes and adds DataMember on all fields when building? But we wont se any changes in our code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using 3.5SP1, it's not necessary to attribute anything- all public members will be serialized on types that aren't otherwise serializable and aren't marked DataContract/DataMember (if it's marked at all, the auto-serialization is disabled). The reference preservation behavior can be set via config + custom serializer setup like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/drnick/replacing-the-serializer-part-1).

Comment: Well I would have done that if I weren't using Silverlight [Serializeable] isn't supported by Silverlight so I am forced to use DataContract/DataMember, but your'e right I want exactly that behaviour.

Comment: This behavior has nothing to do with Serializable, and it works exactly the same way in Silverlight 3 and 4 as it does on 3.5SP1.

Comment: well I will test that approach tomorrow :)

Comment: "The reference preservation behavior can be set via config + custom serializer setup like this.". I've found that this does not work in Silverlight 5. Since the DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior class is internal in Silverlight, there is no way to override the CreateSerializer method to call the constructor with preserveObjectReferences=true. Instead, we're manually adding the [DataContract(IsReference=true)] and [DataMember] attributes as needed. I guess something like PostSharp might be the only other way to handle this.